# Using dictionary for dataframe aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a large 2 dimensional dataframe like this:
 date, user_id, val1, val2

As I need to compute complex functions for each user_id, I do the following:

```
for x in user_id_list :
    dfi= df[ user_id= xx]    
    user_dict[x]['Newmycolname']=  my_fun(dfi)
    user_dict[x]['Newmycolname2']=  my_fun2(dfi)

# map the user_dict to df after
```

This is not very efficient but very flexible since I can compute any kind
of function on the sub-df (dfi). Also, the code can be parallel easily....
at the expense of being fast...

Is there a way to replace the loop for, by a pandas request grouby.agg
and creating new column names?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on each group with conversion to [`pandas.Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html):

```
>>> df.groupby('user_id')
      .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(data=[my_fun(x), my_fun2(x)], index=['Newmycolname', 'Newmycolname2']))
         Newmycolname  Newmycolname2
user_id                             
1                 3.5           17.0
2                 6.0           20.0
```

Without lambda function, just to give clearer understanding what's going on:

```
>>> def worker(x):
...     d = [my_fun(x), my_fun2(x)]
...     i = ['Newmycolname', 'Newmycolname2']
...     return pd.Series(data=d, index=i)
... 
>>> df.groupby('user_id').apply(worker)
         Newmycolname  Newmycolname2
user_id                             
1                 3.5           17.0
2                 6.0           20.0
```

Comment: you answer right after I said their question was confusing ;-)

Comment: @piRSquared thanks, I had to refresh my pandas skills first - unfortunately, I don't spend much time with python recently.